# Is it possible to transfer purchased iTunes songs to a Google Android phone?

Tags: itunes, android

I live in Canada and I've accumulated a wealth of purchased music from the iTunes store. I have an iPhone and I'm considering of moving to an Android mobile device. My question is, can I easily transfer my purchased iTunes songs to my Android device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use iTunes to convert them to MP3, you can then copy the MP3 files to your Android phone.

Comment: Google Music seems to work just fine on importing M4A files. I sync my iTunes to Google Music and my purchased music appears on my Android phone.